# multiple-value "crypto/rand".Int() in single-value context

Tags: go, cryptography

I am trying to generate a random number using the library crypto/rand. The earlier implementation of this function used math/rand, but I need to use crypto/rand. This is my function below

```
func GenerateNum() (num string) {
num = fmt.Sprintf("02:fc:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x", rand.Int(rand.Reader, big.NewInt(256)),
rand.Int(rand.Reader, big.NewInt(256)), rand.Int(rand.Reader, big.NewInt(256)),
rand.Int(rand.Reader, big.NewInt(256))
)
return
}
```

I am fairly new to this language and hence not able to figure out what should be done.

Comment: [crypto/rand.Int()](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/#Int) returns a big int AND an error. You need to handle the error (or explicitly ignore it which is not recommended).

Comment: func rand.Int(rand io.Reader, max *big.Int) (n *big.Int, err error) returns 2 values.But it is used in a single-value context

Comment: @Tiya Jose How do I handle the 2 return values. Any pointers?

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/basics/6

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (although this might not be the best approach)

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/big"
)

func cryptoRandSecure() *big.Int {
    nBig, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, big.NewInt(256))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    return nBig
}

func GenerateNum() (num string) {
    n1 := cryptoRandSecure()
    n2 := cryptoRandSecure()
    n3 := cryptoRandSecure()
    n4 := cryptoRandSecure()
    num = fmt.Sprintf("02:fc:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x", n1, n2, n3, n4)
    return
}

func main() {
    num := GenerateNum()
    fmt.Println(num)
}
```

Comment: what if I get an err in cryptoRandSecure, how do I handle, I can't panic.  Any idea?.